# How decrypt pdf text layer?

Tags: pdf, decryption

This pdf is crypted. Cant make quotes and copy text, text is garbled.

http://www.stolyarov.info/books/pdf/progintro_e2v2.pdf

This ghostscript help partitialy.

```
ghostscript -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=unencrypted.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f encrypted.pdf
```

After that on Andriod readers text is still garbled when i use quotes or copy them.

How decrypt such pdfs?

Comment: Is this your PDF that you encrypted?  Otherwise have you asked the owner of the PDF?

Comment: PDFs that where you copy text but get garbage can't be "decrypted" because the operation that has been applied is not reversible. Effectively the PDF is like an image containing text. The only way to get something meaningful out of such PDF files is apply an OCR program on it.

Comment: Ok thanks and how i do OCR this pdf using ocrmypdf?
https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html

And why after upper gs script operation partially is decrypted this pdf but only under Linux and Windows pdf software, under Android its still garbled?

Comment: ***fix***
after upper gs script operation partially is decrypted this pdf but only under Linux pdf software, under Android and Windows its still garbled?

Comment: FYI That document is *not* encrypted. It is just a normal PDF file where the application creating the file provided wrong translations from the codes that display the characters to the characters themselves. This might have been done accidentally or on purpose.

Comment: it's made on purpose. is there a way to make it normal without OCR?